# Wrong pip in conda env

Tags: python, pip, conda

I have a conda env called birdid.

While working in the env (i.e. I did `source activate bird_dev`), showing the list of the packages give

```
(bird_dev)...$ conda list
# packages in environment at /home/jul/Development/miniconda/envs/bird_dev:
#
...
pep8                      1.6.2                    py27_0  
pip                       7.1.2                    py27_0  
pixman                    0.26.2                        0  
...
```

but when trying to see what `pip` is used I get

```
(bird_dev)...$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

while the correct `python` is found

```
(bird_dev)...$ which python
/home/jul/Development/miniconda/envs/bird_dev/bin/python
```

Anybody can help?

**Edit: more details about the installed versions**

Check which -a pip

```
(bird_dev)...$ which -a pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
/usr/bin/pip
```

The version in `/usr/bin/pip` is quite old.

```
(bird_dev)...$ /usr/bin/pip -V
pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)    
(bird_dev)....$ /usr/local/bin/pip -V
pip 6.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

There is actually no pip in the env

```
$ ll /home/jul/Development/miniconda/envs/bird_dev/bin/ | grep pip
```

returns nothing

there is one pip in `/home/jul/Development/miniconda/bin/pip`

```
$ /home/jul/Development/miniconda/bin/pip -V
pip 6.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

but it is not the version listed by `conda list`, and it is a python script (!)

```
$ cat /home/jul/Development/miniconda/bin/pip
#!/home/jul/Development/miniconda/bin/python
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from pip import main

    sys.exit(main())
```

**Edit: echo $PATH**

```
(bird_dev)...$ echo $PATH
/home/jul/Development/miniconda/envs/bird_dev/bin:/home/jul/torch/install/bin:/home/jul/torch/install/bin:/home/jul/torch/install/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

**Edit: try to force install**

```
(bird_dev)...$ conda install --force pip
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: .
Package plan for installation in environment /home/jul/Development/miniconda/envs/bird_dev:

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    pip: 7.1.2-py27_0 --> 7.1.2-py27_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

[      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################################################################################################################################################| 100%
Extracting packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################################################################################################################################################| 100%
Unlinking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################################################################################################################################################| 100%
Linking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################################################################################################################################################| 100%
(bird_dev)...$ which pip
/home/jul/Development/miniconda/envs/bird_dev/bin/pip
(bird_dev)...$ /home/jul/Development/miniconda/envs/bird_dev/bin/pip -V
pip 6.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
(bird_dev)...$ cat /home/jul/Development/miniconda/envs/bird_dev/bin/pip 
#!/home/jul/Development/miniconda/envs/bird_dev/bin/python
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from pip import main

    sys.exit(main())
```

Weird.

Comment: can you add `which -a pip`?

Comment: Done. It's even worse, it seems that I have two pip in the system.

Comment: Can pip in env be a symbolic link?

Comment: it's pretty normal to have multiple `pip` version when scanning the whole path. What is more surprising is that the pip version in your environment is not listed, although it really should've been. I would try `conda install --force pip` and check `which pip` again afterwards. If this doesn't help you could add the output of `echo $PATH` for further debugging.

Comment: @alpert I edited my question with more details.

Comment: @cel: I added `echo $PATH` too, but it seems ok: it first check the env bin folder...

Comment: I would check if `PYTHONPATH` or `PYTHONHOME` is set and try unsetting those. This is really strange and I am running out of ideas.

Comment: I unset PYTHONPATH and I get the correct pip. It had a folder containing a python module `pip` which was probably the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @cel can you add an answer with your comment on PYTHONPATH so that I can accept it?

Comment: the answer by @asmeurer is perfectly fine IMO. I was more interested in understanding the problem than in putting together a well formatted answer. If you feel that the answer is not detailed enough to describe the full problem it is perfectly fine to self-answer as well!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably have `PYTHONPATH` set. I would recommend unsetting it, and removing any lines from `~/.bashrc` that set it. It will cause any of your conda environments' Pythons to look in that location before themselves.

Comment: Yes, I unset PYTHONPATH and it worked. See the corresponding comments to my question.

Comment: I really wonder whether there is a case for using PYTHONPATH and python environments. PYTHONPATH is buried in the bash profile and easy to forget. When you are in an env and think you are 'isolated' , the PYTHONPATH is a sneaky snake that makes python look outside the sandboxed env.

Comment: PYTHONPATH can be useful, for instance, for making Python load a module from a local directory instead of the installed version. The issue is with setting it permanently in your bash profile, which causes it to globally affect all Python executables, which fundamentally goes against the idea of isolated environments. I would recommend only using PYTHONPATH on the command line, and then, only on the same line as the command you want to run (that is, don't export it).

Answer (score 1):

You can try removing the wrong pip installation.

```
rm -rf <path from `which pip`>
```

Comment: This works quite well in practice, since the pip in the base environment is / should mostly not be used. A way to avoid issues with multiple pips installed is to use miniconda, which ships with a minimal base-environment