# Wrong pip version for anaconda's environments. What should I do to correct the pip version when activate a env using `conda activate`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda, conda

I have 4 envs in my anaconda as listed below.

```
>>> conda info --envs
base                     /home/gph/anaconda3
py36_torch0.4         *  /home/gph/anaconda3/envs/py36_torch0.4
py37_torch1.1            /home/gph/anaconda3/envs/py37_torch1.1
python3.6                /home/gph/anaconda3/envs/python3.6
```

In both py36_torch0.4 and py37_torch1.1, I did some test.

```
>>>(py36_torch0.4) gph@gph-1050Ti:~ $ whereis pip
pip: /home/gph/.local/bin/pip3.5 
/home/gph/.local/bin/pip 
/home/gph/anaconda3/envs/py36_torch0.4/bin/pip3.6 
/home/gph/anaconda3/envs/py36_torch0.4/bin/pip

(py36_torch0.4) gph@gph-1050Ti:~ $ pip -V
pip 19.1.1 from /home/gph/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)

(py37_torch1.1) gph@gph-1050Ti:~ $ whereis pip
pip: /home/gph/.local/bin/pip3.5 
/home/gph/.local/bin/pip 
/home/gph/anaconda3/envs/py37_torch1.1/bin/pip

(py37_torch1.1) gph@gph-1050Ti:~ $ pip -V
pip 19.1.1 from /home/gph/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)
```

We can see that for each `env_name` we have `envs/env_name/bin/pip`, but the output of `pip -V` is always `/home/gph/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)`.
What is wrong? What should I do to make the pip version right when activate a specific env?

I have tried unset PYTHONPATH as told in this question: [Wrong pip in conda env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32329260/wrong-pip-in-conda-env). But it is no use.

Comment: pip3.5 is the first binary in your path, try typing pip3.6 -V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've installed `pip` outside of the conda environments, directly into your home directory. This takes precedence over everything that's installed in conda.

If you want to benefit from isolation of conda environments, you cannot install packages on the user level. This will get rid of all of them (but maybe also some more):

```
rm -rf /home/gph/.local
```

You might want to have a look at what else is installed in `/home/gph/.local` before actually removing it.

Comment: What kind of packages will be installed to `/home/gph/.local`? I have `bin/`, `lib/` and `share/` there. And in `bin/` are pip things, in `lib/` is `python3.5/`, while in `share/` there are many packages for everyday use.

Comment: @ToughMind Packages you install with `pip --user` go into `~/.local/`. Don't do that if you're working with `conda`.

Comment: I delete the `bin` and `lib` in `.local` and everything becomes right. I think delete pip and python things in `.local` helps

Answer (score 3):

Use pip as a module called by the Python interpreter of your env.

`python -m pip install some_package` where `python` is the one active on your env, for example `/home/gph/anaconda3/envs/python3.6/bin/python`.