# How do I properly install my own local development package in Conda?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, conda

This is the first time I've tried developing a package rather than just scripts and a lot of it is very confusing to me. I am using Windows 10 with Python 3.7 installed and managed via Conda 4.7.11.

**TLDR: Conda packages aren't properly isolated from each other when using pip install -e.**

I have a basic package structured like this:

```
----my_package
    |   LICENSE
    |   README.md
    |   setup.py
    |
    |---my_package
            my_module.py
            __init__.py
```

In `my_module.py` is:

```
def cool_thing():
    print("This is a cool thing!")
```

In `__init__.py` is:

```
from .my_module import cool_thing
```

So when I run Python from the outer `my_package` directory, I can do this:

```
$ python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Ana
conda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import my_package
>>> my_package.cool_thing()
This is a cool thing!
```

So far, so good. Now I want to install the package locally to a virtual Conda environment. My `setup.py` file has this inside:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name = "my_package",
      version = "0.1",
      description = "Do something cool!",
      author = "Me",
      license = "MIT",
      packages = ["my_package"],
      zip_safe = False)
```

In the terminal I do this:

```
conda create -n env-my-package
conda activate env-my-package
conda install pip
```

I read in a lot of places that this is how you're supposed to install local development packages:

```
pip install -e .
```

It tells me:

```
Obtaining file:///C:/long/path/to/my_package
Installing collected packages: my-package
  Running setup.py develop for my-package
Successfully installed my-package
```

`pip list` tells me it's installed:

```
$ pip list
Package      Version   Location
------------ --------- --------------------------
certifi      2019.6.16
my-package   0.1       c:\long\path\to\my_package
pip          19.2.2
setuptools   41.0.1
wheel        0.33.4
wincertstore 0.2
```

And if I navigate to a different directory I can still import it in Python:

```
cd ..
python
$ python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import my_package
>>> my_package.cool_thing()
This is a cool thing!
```

So this seems fine. **But then look at what happens when I switch to a different Conda environment:**

```
conda deactivate
conda activate env-something-else
python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import my_package
```

The package somehow gets imported anyway, without an error message, despite the fact that **we are in a totally separate Conda environment without `my_package` installed.** On the other hand, actually trying to use the package results in an error:

```
>>> my_package.cool_thing()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'my_package' has no attribute 'cool_thing'
```

Investigating further, `dir(my_package)` shows it has no non-dunder attributes:

```
>>> dir(my_package)
['__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

`my_package.__file__` outputs `None`, while `my_package.__path__` gives the path to the directory where the original files are: `C:\long\path\to\my_package`.

So it seems like the Conda environments aren't properly isolated. It can still see the package when it's not supposed to, even if it can't use functions from it. Before you ask, yes, I did make sure to run `pip install -e` with the original `env-my-package` environment activated.

This has made me completely distrust that what I'm doing in my Conda environment stays in my Conda environment. If it "leaks" in this way, what else might leak? I don't want to accidentally pollute any of my other projects while working on this package. Thankfully I'm able to uninstall it using pip and return to a clean state, but still, I can't go any further until I figure this out. My ultimate question:

**What is the proper way to develop a package when using Conda?**

I hope you'll forgive me for writing this all out to the point of tediousness, but I wanted to make sure I covered all the details just in case any are important.

Comment: do you have pip installed outside the environment? Conda may be using a different pip than you think, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56593879/wrong-pip-version-for-anacondas-environments-what-should-i-do-to-correct-the-p

Comment: Pip is installed in several different conda environments but I remember checking which one was being used by running `which pip` in the terminal. It was the one for the environment I wanted. It's also not a case of conflicting with system Python -- there is no system Python. Before I installed conda there was no Python on this machine at all. I will try the `python -m pip install` suggestion at the next opportunity though.